# Mirror Eclipse workspaces in W10/Linux-Mint Dual-boot

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint

I have found out that Eclipse workspaces contain configuration information in addition to project code and compiler products, and that is why I cannot share them between OS's.  I don't want to get fancy (Version control systems) because it's just me using them on one machine.

Is it possible to symbolic-link each source file from the Windows workspace to the Linux workspace?  Has anyone done this and created a script already?  I would probably write it run each time Linux logs in.  Any problems in doing this that I don't see?

Comment: These days, using something like Git isn't "getting fancy", it is a basic component of software development, even for a single developer. Especially if you are comparing it to a bunch of symbolic links and custom login script. I suggest to use the proper tool for the job rather than invent your own. Keep the code in Git, and .gitignore the environment dependent config files. It is the standard method that everyone uses. As a bonus, you get all the other benefits of version control.

Comment: You need two workspaces for that, but the project folders/directories can be the same and outside of the workspace. Import the projects without copying them e.g. via _File > Open Projects from File System..._

Comment: Many thanks, howlger!